# How to generate emacs manual to pdf by myself?

Tags: manual

Are there any off-the-rack way to generate a pdf version GNU Emacs Manual (and other manuals GNU Emacs brings with) from GNU Emacs source code or the texinfo files by myself?

I've found a free version of GNU Emacs Manual of version 24.5 and want to print a newer version of this manual.  I also want to print a manual of GNU Calc.

----- UPDATED -----

I've found these lines in GNU Calc's manual:

> The Calc manual can be printed, but because the manual is so large,
>   you should only make a printed copy if you really need it.  To print
>   the manual, you will need the TeX typesetting program (this is a free
>   program by Donald Knuth at Stanford University) as well as the
>   ‘texindex’ program and ‘texinfo.tex’ file, both of which can be
>   obtained from the FSF as part of the ‘texinfo’ package.  To print the
>   Calc manual in one huge tome, you will need the Emacs source, which
>   contains the source code to this manual, ‘calc.texi’.  Change to the
>   ‘doc/misc’ subdirectory of the Emacs source distribution, which
>   contains source code for this manual, and type ‘make calc.pdf’. 
>   (Don’t worry if you get some “overfull box” warnings while TeX runs.) 
>   The result will be this entire manual as a pdf file.

but when I tried to run

```
$ pwd
~/gits/emacs/doc/misc
$ make calc.pdf
make: *** No rule to make target 'calc.pdf'. Stop.
```

I am wondering whether this is because the calc's manual is outdated and the writer didn't keep it updated.

Can you help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer by myself:

After entering the directory of emacs source code:

```
$ sh autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ cd doc/misc
$ make calc.pdf

$ cd ../emacs
$ make elisp.pdf
```